# In the anime Fairy Tail, how many types of God Slayer Elemental magic are there?

Tags: fairy-tail

Other than the two main types of [God Slayer Magic](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/God_Slayer_Magic) seen in the Anime and Manga series' (e.g. air and fire), what other elemental magics are there?

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to the Manga "Fairy Tale", in which God Slayers use "God Slayer Magic" and asking how many there are. See http://fairytailfanon.wikia.com/wiki/God_Slayer

Comment: @S.Fruggiero a better link would be http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page as i believe the Wikia you linked would have Fanon material in it aswell and could give the asker an incorrect answer in terms of the canon

Comment: @winterwolfsound. Although I appreciate that English may not be your first language, can you please attempt to make your questions a little clearer. Also, you've incorrectly tagged both of your questions. Can you have a read of the tag wikis (they pop up as you type in your tags) to make sure you're choosing correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Fire, Sky and Lightning god slaying Magic.

these are the details of the episodes where I saw them:
season 4 - ep 5 is where you can find the fire god slayer.

Season 6(episode 169) is where you can find Sky God Slayer.

season 7(episode 185) you can find Lightning God Slayer Magic(Orga). I don't follow Manga much so this is how i came to know about them

Comment: A good, short, accurate answer. That's an upvote from me.

Comment: A few examples wouldn't hurt though.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell (solely going by the Wikia), there are three main kinds of God Slayer Magic; Air and fire that you've already mentioned and [Lightning God Slayer Magic](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_God_Slayer_Magic) seen in the manga in episodes #273 and #320.